voicing contrast vs aspiration contrast in English
we know that voicing contrast is existing in English but aspiration is not contrast. For example, the word gap /ɡæp/ and the word cap /kæp/. However, If we look at the phonetic transcription, these two words become [ɡ̊æp] and [kʰæp] respectively, the voicing contrast is realized as aspiration contrast: unaspirated devoiced velar stop vs aspirated voiceless velar stop, does anyone know what the reason is here?

For questions like this, we have to start with what symbols like g g̊ k kʰ actually mean (acoustically). If you record someone producing these sounds, and go through and analyze the audio, you'll notice a difference in voice onset time—the timespan between the release of the closure and the start of voicing.
A lot of languages have a binary contrast in VOT, where sounds with a low VOT are analyzed as one phoneme, and sounds with a high VOT are analyzed as a different phoneme. Categorical perception experiments can measure where exactly the distinction is—and it's actually a remarkably sharp dividing line!—and it differs between languages.
We have the terms "voiced", "voiceless/unaspirated", and "aspirated" from the analysis of languages that have a three-way distinction. So conventionally, if this dividing line is very far to the "voiced" side (like it is in Spanish), we call it a "voiced-voiceless" distinction, and if it's very far to the "aspirated" side (like it is in Mandarin), we call it an "unaspirated-aspirated" distinction.
But what if it's somewhere in the middle, like in English? Our high-VOT stops aren't as aspirated as in Mandarin, but our low-VOT stops aren't as voiced as in Spanish, either. Which terminology should we use?
Well, usually what breaks the tie is that /g k/ looks nicer than /k kʰ/ in transcriptions. Both of them are about equally correct, insofar as they indicate "the one on the left has lower VOT than the one on the right", and our low-VOT stops are kinda voiced, and our high-VOT stops are kinda aspirated. But if you want to really dig into the acoustic details, no IPA symbol is precise enough; you need to start looking at spectrograms and VOT measurements directly.
P.S. This is why the terms "fortis" (meaning "higher VOT") and "lenis" (meaning "lower VOT") are sometimes preferred, since they don't commit to one analysis over the other.

(PPS Yes it's true that there's more to voicing/aspiration than a single VOT measurement, but simplifications have to be made for a good explanation!)

Thank you, it seems that I understand this question more now！
